# Regular expression to replace all "<" and " >" tags with "&lt;" and "&gt;" in <![CDATA]> tag?

Tags: java, regex, xml-parsing

How can I use a regular expression to replace all `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` in `<![CDATA]>` tag?

```
<![CDATA[<p style='text-align:justify;'>Some text <b>BoldM/b>jsajhsj </p>]]>
```

should be converted to this:

```
<![CDATA[&lt;p style='text-align:justify;'&gt;Some text &lt; b&gt;Bold &lt;/b&gt;jsajhsj </p>]]>
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `CDATA` that you shouldn't need to?

Comment: Required reading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 The question was about regex and HTML, but the same comments apply to XML.

Comment: Actually am parsing RSS feeds using SAX parser(Android). I am getting error like "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ?@1:2 in java.io.StringReader@407ed818)" ..

Comment: If it's happening at line 1 column 2 it's because CDATA can't occur at top level. It has to be an element inside a tag.

Comment: What is the url of the RSS feed you try to read ? Or can you post its content in your anwser ?

Comment: @Alex :      http://www.udayavanienglish.com/feed.aspx?cat_id=799&languageid=14

Comment: @tilak I have checked the RSS feed against various validators and it doesn't seem valid. However, can you add to your question the code that parse this feed ?